# How to create a high resolution QR code image with imagemagick?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, imagemagick

How do I create a 300 DPI QR code with imagemagick? Where I can define width and height in mm.

I have searched on rubygems and found some QR code libraries. But not found a proper solution with imagemagick. I need to generate a ton of qr codes therefor I need some QR library to work with imagemagick because I need to add additional graphic like some background.

Comment: did you resolve this issue?? if yes then how ?? i am also having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rqrcode](http://whomwah.github.com/rqrcode/) is a good place to start

Comment: There is a handy extension called 'rqrcode_png' that converts the qr object to an image file (https://github.com/DCarper/rqrcode_png).  I just did the example in the readme and produced a PNG of a QR code without difficulty.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
mogrify -density 300 img.jpg
```

Comment: @Rails beginner: Imagemagick are generally not used for drawing (although it does have basic drawing capability), you'll need a QR code generator library in whatever language you're using, generate a QR code big enough, and set the image density with imagemagick and perhaps rescale as needed.

Comment: here's my downvote because it doesn't really "create" a qr code, the code above has **nothing** to do with QR code.